# How can I exit a multi-line shell script, on fail, and still log the error stream to a file?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create a shell script (e.g., test.sh) that executes multiple commands, and redirect each command's stdout and stderr to a specific log file.

But, if a command fails, after writing stderr to the log file, I want to abort, rather than continuing with the remaining commands.

Will the following work, or do I need to do something different?

```
    command1 > log1.txt 2>&1
    command2 > log2.txt 2>&1
    command3 > log3.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Note that the order of operations for `foo >out` is that it *first* opens `out`, and *then* runs `foo` (with its output streaming to the previously-opened file as it's written). Thus, you don't need to worry about an immediate exit preventing the file from being written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that each command returns an error code (ie non-zero) on failure, then you can use that to bail the containing script eg:

```
if command1 > log1.txt 2>&1; then
  if command2 > log2.txt 2>&1; then
    command3 > log3.txt 2>&1
  fi
fi
```

Or, more tersely:

```
command1 > log1.txt 2>&1 &&
command2 > log2.txt 2>&1 &&
command3 > log3.txt 2>&1
```